# Android - Play sound in a class File?

Tags: android, media-player, ogg, playsound

I can play a sound in my activity. e.g.:

```
public class APP extends Activity {

MediaPlayer btnClick;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

btnClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button_click);

    }

... on Button Click play sound ...
btnClick.start();
...

}
```

But I have no idea how to play a sound in a class file?

```
public class test {
...
}
```

Is that not possible? I tried so many variations. In the class file, I can't play a sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to forward your `Context` to the class in the constructor.

Add a class member for your `Context`:

```
Context mContext;
```

Then, add a constructor that takes a `Context`:

```
public test (Context c){
   mContext = c;
}
```

Instantiate your class using this constructor:

```
Test test = new Test(this); //Assuming you call this in an Activity
```

Lastly, where you want to play your sound in your class, use `mContext` as the `Context`:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.button_click);
```

If you want to instantiate your class in a FrameLayout, use this code:

```
Test test = new Test(getContext()); //Assuming you call this in a subclass of FrameLayout
```

Comment: When I try to use this: Test test = new Test(this); -> The app crashes

Comment: In what class are you performing this code? What is the superclass?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34327/discussion-between-user2080833-and-fd)

Answer (score 2):

You can only specify mediaPlayer in the test class and then call the method from test class which involves the mediaPlayerSettings. Test class itself can't play because it doesn't extend activity.

But if you want to get the method from class test do it like that:

```
public class test
{

    private static MediaPlayer mp;

    public static void startPlayingSound(Context con)
       {
         mp= MediaPlayer.create(con, R.raw.sound);
         mp.start();
       }

//and to stop it use this method below

    public static void stopPlayingSound(Context con)
      { 
       if(!mp.isPlaying())
         {
           mp.release();
           mp = null;
         }
     }

}
```

Consequently in the Activity call it like that:

```
//for start
test.startPlayingSound(this);
//and for stop
test.stopPlayingSound(this);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I want to call it in the class file. I think the problem is here, that I don't extend the activity. That what you said.

Comment: If you want to call it in the test class file then test class has to extend the Activity.

Comment: I extend in my class FrameLayout. Can I give two things: extends FrameLayout, Activity ???

Comment: No no, you can't that is against Java, the language itself doesn't allow to extend two classes. If you want the class test run in foreground or background extend it as Activity for foreground or Service for background playing of the sound.